# How to upload a file in to object storage using node js call

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, object-storage

Iam trying to create a post call which basically takes a file(eg img,pdf file) and then it need to upload in to object storage on bluemix.I was able to authenticate and get the token and create the authurl.I just need to pass file which we upload along with the url.But Iam out of ideas how I can get the file uploaded from postman to be passed to that url with in the post call..Below is my code

```
app.post('/uploadfile',function(req,res){
         getAuthToken().then(function(token){
                    if(!token){
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                    else{
                        var fileName = req.body.file;
                        console.log("data",file);
                        console.log(SOFTLAYER_ID_V3_AUTH_URL,"url");
                        var apiUrl = SOFTLAYER_ID_V3_AUTH_URL + config.projectId + '/' + containerName + fileName ;
                        url : apiurl,
                        method :'PUT',
                        headers :{
                            'X-Auth-Token': token
                        },function(error, response, body) {
                            if(!error && response.statusCode == 201) {
                                res.send(response.headers);
                            } else {
                                console.log(error, body);
                                res.send(body);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })

            });
```

Can someone help here.

Comment: Did [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984333/how-to-upload-a-file-in-to-object-storage-using-node-js-call/42984620#42984620) help you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Express, you should use something like:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload
- https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy
- https://github.com/expressjs/multer
- https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty
- https://github.com/mscdex/reformed

Without a body parser that handles file uploads you will not be able to get the uploaded file in the Express request handler.

Then, you need to pass the uploaded file to the request that you're making.

For that you should use this module:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluemix-object-storage

There is no need to reinvent the wheel when there are tested and eay to use solutions available. Especially when you're dealing with sensitive information like API keys and secrets I would not advice you to implement your own solution from scratch, unless you really know what you're doing. And if you really know what you're doing, then you don't need to seek advice for things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official Object Storage SDK for Node.js:

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-objectstorage-serversdk-nodejs

Connect to Object Storage:

```
var credentials = {
    projectId: 'project-id',
    userId: 'user-id',
    password: 'password',
    region: ObjectStorage.Region.DALLAS
};
var objStorage = new ObjectStorage(credentials);
```

Create a container:

```
objstorage.createContainer('container-name')
    .then(function(container) {
        // container - the ObjectStorageContainer that was created
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // AuthTokenError if there was a problem refreshing authentication token
        // ServerError if any unexpected status codes were returned from the request
    });
}
```

Create a new object or update an existing one:

```
container.createObject('object-name', data)
    .then(function(object) {
        // object - the ObjectStorageObject that was created
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // TimeoutError if the request timed out
        // AuthTokenError if there was a problem refreshing authentication token
        // ServerError if any unexpected status codes were returned from the request
    });
```

Comment: when I tried to list the container using the above code it is giving me the error E:\watson\bluemixobjectstorage\node_modules\bluemix-objectstorage\lib\HttpClient.js:50
    this.authToken.expiration = body.token.expires_at;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'expires_at' of undefined

Can u help in this

Comment: Hi @user7350714, it looks like someone else had the same issue here: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-objectstorage-serversdk-nodejs/issues/4. You may want to ask to reopen the issue so the developers can look into it. It is possible that the Object Storage service changed their specification, so it no longer returns an `expires_at` parameter as required.